# expo cannot be loaded on terminal(npm run - works but not expo start)

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, expo

expo : File D:\Users*user*\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is
disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- expo start
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException       
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see this error follow these steps:

1. Open Windows PowerShell with Run as Administrator.
2. Use `Get-ExecutionPolicy` on Windows PowerShell to see the execution policy.

   Most probably there you would see (Restricted) this command. So, the main reason-running scripts on this system are Restricted.
3. Now we need to change this policy to allow the operation. Use this command to make it "Unrestricted":

   ```
   Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
   ```

   Here you will get a prompt message and you should press **'Y'** to change from Restricted to Unrestricted.

To ensure, you may check the execution policy by `Get-ExecutionPolicy` again.

The possible output should be (Unrestricted)

Now you can use the `expo start` command on your machine.